# How do I redirect stdin from a shell script to a command in the shell script?

Tags: bash, stdin

How do I redirect stdin from a shell script to a command in the shell script?  I am trying to pass the stdin to a java System.in stream.

I want to replace

```
find . -type f | $JAVA_HOME/bin/java com.domain.BatchProcess
```

with

```
 find . -type f | ./batch.sh
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the command:

```
$JAVA_HOME/bin/java com.domain.BatchProcess
```

is expecting input from stdin, then putting it in a script and running your second command will work.

Answer (score 8):

If you exec the command within the script, it will replace the shell and inherit it's file descriptors,
including stdin,stdout and stderr.

Answer (score 1):

It does it automatically.